# Wordpress custom post type yearly/monthly archives

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Is there anyway to have yearly or monthly archives with custom post types in wordpress?
I've searched far and wide to no avail.
I would imagine the url structure to be this:

http://sitename/custom-post-type/year/month

Anyone?

Comment: This plugin gets the permalink structure working: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-permalinks/
but still can't generate a list the gives correct links to yearly archive for a custom post type.

Answer (score 0):

My plugin [Custom Post Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-permalinks/) lets you tweak the permalink settings. However, as of now, it only works on non-hierarchical post types. I'm working on a new release that will allow both types.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. Replace CPT in array with your CPT name.

This function will convert the the following URL

> http://example.net/CPT/2016/06

to

> http://example.net/?post_type=CPT&m=201606

which is actually used by wordpress.

```
add_action('init', 'date_cpt_rewrites');

function date_cpt_rewrites() {
    $custom_post_types = array('CPT'); //some example post types
    foreach ( $custom_post_types as $post_type ) {
        $rule = '^' . $post_type . '/(\d+)/(\d+)/?$';
        $rewrite = 'index.php?post_type=' . $post_type . '&m=$matches[1]$matches[2]';
        add_rewrite_rule($rule,$rewrite,'top');
    }


}
```